# Remove first leading 0 from varchar with MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How I can remove only the first 0 character from a varchar?

For example '000303'  ==> '00303'

I tried this without success, all the 0 characters are removed:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('000303', PATINDEX('%[^0]%', '000303'),LEN('000303'));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `STUFF` Function

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT('000303',1) = '0' THEN STUFF('000303',1,1,'') ELSE '000303' END
```

or Use `RIGHT` Function

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT('000303',1) = '0' THEN RIGHT('000303', LEN('000303')-1) ELSE '000303' END
```

Instead of `LEFT('000303',1) = '0'` *check* you can also use

`charindex('0','000303') = 1` or

`'000303' LIKE '0%'` *(ughai suggestion)*

Comment: Saw this question and thought, `STUFF` fits perfectly here and then saw your answer. :). well you could even use `'000303' LIKE '0%'` if you are looking for alternatives for `LEFT('000303',1) = '0'`

Comment: Thanks, I will explore the STUFF function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT RIGHT(MyColumn, LEN(MyColumn) - 1)
```

This will remove the first character from the varchar column.

If it is specific to 0 then try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT(MyColumn,1) = '0' 
     THEN RIGHT(MyColumn, LEN(MyColumn) - 1)  
     ELSE
     MyColumn END
```

Comment: First one strips always the first character, second one returns NULL if the column doesn't start with '0'

Comment: When I saw the original answer, before it was ninja edited, it only said "Try this:

SELECT RIGHT(MyColumn, LEN(MyColumn) - 1) 
This will remove the first character from the varchar column", which is an incomplete answer.  The ninja edit is not an improvement, for the reasons JamesZ stated.

Comment: @JamesZ:- I have already mentioned for the first one. The second part which you made makes a relevant sense, I have updated my answer for that. Thanks for pointing that

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables:- Yes the second point makes sense. I have made changes. Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT(Mycol,1) = '0' THEN SUBSTRING(MyCOL, 2, LEN(MyCOL)) END
```